# What is the best way to hide a CALayer (without animation)?

Tags: ios, calayer

I have a number of full screen CALayers as part of a single UIView. Depending on how the user interacts with the view, I need to show one layer and hide all others. I'm currently doing this by changing the opacity, i.e.

Layer to hide: [layer setOpacity:0];
Layer to show: [layer setOpacity:1];

For a reason I don't quite understand, this seems to create a flashing effect on the screen. Partially to avoid this, but also because I have the impression that opacity changes can affect performances, I'm wondering if changing opacity is actually the best way to hide and/or show CALayers, e.g. should I consider changing the zPosition or changing its position so that it no longer appears on screen.

I don't want to animate the transition by the way.

Thanks in advance for any pointers or help.

Comment: Have you tried just moving the layer you want visible in front of the currently visible layer using `insertSublayer:above:`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The normal way to hide a layer is setting its `hidden` property to `YES`, but it's no harm to set its `opacity` to 0.0 to achieve that, which depends on your usage scenario.
If your `CALayer` is not your `UIView`'s underlying layer(the `UIView` instance's `layer` property), change the `opacity` or `hidden` properties will trigger animation by default. To prevent that, add this code before changing these properties:

```
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact, the thing I really needed was the [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES] as the animation was causing the 'flashing'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

CALayer has a property called "hidden", try setting that to YES and NO instead of switching opacities.

Layer to hide: [layer setHidden:YES];

Layer to show: [layer setHidden:NO];

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it animates but that's NOT what the author of the question wants